# How to dynamically delete rows in DataList c# asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datalist

Looking for a way to dynamically delete rows from a datalist, providing a user a way to 'clean up' their input interface.  The asp datalist gets loaded from SQL, then the user gets to manipulate the table before sending it on to another database.

I have a functioning 'addRows' by using a datatable session variable, adding rows to it then re-binding to the datalist, however I can't seem to get the same function with deleting rows.

Current logic is to use datalist 'delRows' command, get current typed-in or modified data from the asp datalist, assign it to a datatable, loop thru datatable and delete rows where certain fields are empty, then re-bind datatable to asp datalist.

Current code workup, but cannot get dt filled, error "dt = null" :

```
        if (e.CommandName == "delRows")
        {                         
            DataList DataList1 = (DataList)FindControl("DataList1"); //find datalist in current state
            Session["dataList1"] = DataList1;  //assign datalist to session variable     
            DataTable dt = Session["dataList1"] as DataTable; //populate datatable with datalist session 

            for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
                string check = dr["item_no"].ToString();
                if (check == String.Empty)
                {
                    dr.Delete();
                }
            }

            DataList1.DataSource = dt;
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
```

Hopefully there is a better way to accomplish this!  Not to mention working....

Comment: where are you Binding the Data to the DataList. why don't you just use a DataTable to retrieve your data..?

Comment: where are you assigning values to this variable..?  `Session["dataList1"] = DataList1;` looks backwards

Comment: The Session["dataList1"] gets bound in the addRow command.  The problem that I believe I'm running into is how to get the current datalist state, meaning a user can modify it, but then I need to get that 'current state' and loop thru it.  I was thinking grab it to a session variable, then session it to a datatable (dt), then loop thru table. Session["dataList1"] = DataList1; would grab the found datalist control from the prev line, then assign it to a session variable.

Comment: where ever the data is being captured into the Session Variable is what I would Cast the Session as a DataTable, you may have to come up with your own mechanism of performing the delta check to make sure if the data is current or the data has changed.. I would start with the easiest part first and make sure you can successfully store the data into a Session, there is no OnChange event for a Session variable.. so you may also have to rethink your current process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future info seekers: Had to loop thru table to get most current textbox text into dt, then modify dt datatable in code behind, then rebind dt to datalist.

```
protected void doDataTable(string command, int e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 

    dt.Columns.Add("no", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("desc", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("code", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("measure", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("price", typeof(double));

    foreach (DataListItem item in DataList4.Items) 
    {
        string no = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("no")).Text;
        string desc = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("desc")).Text;
        string code = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("code")).Text;
        string measure = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("measure")).Text;
        int qty = Convert.ToInt16(((TextBox)item.FindControl("qty")).Text);
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)item.FindControl("price")).Text.TrimStart('$'));

        dt.Rows.Add(no, desc, code, measure, qty, price);
    }

    if (command == "add")
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        DataList4.DataSource = dt;
        DataList4.DataBind();
    }
    else if (command == "del")
    {
        dt.Rows[e].Delete();

        DataList4.DataSource = dt;
        DataList4.DataBind();                   
    }
}
```

Called with:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "addRow")
    {   
        doDataTable("add", e.Item.ItemIndex);
    }

    if (e.CommandName == "delRows")
    {   
        doDataTable("del", e.Item.ItemIndex);
    }
}
```